# How to add independent increment counter to new item in array. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

In my example, i have two arrays. 
First  array - values, second - zeros for incremental counter.
Any new item have own counter button for him. 
But it is not working, and i do not know why. If i push several buttons, i see chaotioc behavior in arrays

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/jqr0nzte/27/)

1. How to repair it?
2. How to do counter function without button?

   Example: if i loading page, i see 3 elements. Counters begining counting  from 0. After 10 seconds i add new element. Old counters continue to work, but counter in new element start from 0.

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#page',
  data: {
   arr: [1, 2 ,3],
    count: [0, 0 ,0]
  },
  methods: {
   addEll: function() {
     this.arr.push(this.arr.length + 1);
      this.count.push(0);
    },
    incrementio: function(val) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
        Vue.set(this.count, this.count[val], 0);
        this.count[val]++;
      }, 1000);
     },
  },
  computed: {
   visibleList: function(){
     return this.arr;
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="page">
<button v-on:click="addEll">Add element</button>
{{ arr }}
{{ count }}
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in visibleList">
        {{item}}
        <button v-on:click="incrementio(index)">Counter: {{count[index]}}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you trying to count lifetime of each value. Here is my approach. Firstly I tied the value and its counter together in one object as I find it more efficient. Moving on, I defined `interval` property, because not doing so (The compiler automatically defines it in global scope) may cause unwanted behaviour and it is regarded as an error in `strict` mode. I also removed unnecessary `visibleList` computed property from your code. And last but not least I added `clearInterval` function in `beforeDestroy` hook as it is a good habit. (In your particular case it might be unnecessary to do so but if it was a component reused many times it would be very important to have it as it frees up the memory.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#page',
  data: {
    arr: [{
      value: 1,
      counter: 0
    }],
    interval: null
  },
  mounted () {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.arr.map(x => x.counter++);
    }, 1000);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  methods: {
    addEll () {
      this.arr.push({
        value: this.arr.length + 1,
        counter: 0
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="page">
  <button v-on:click="addEll">Add</button> {{ arr }}
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in arr">
      {{item.value}} Counter: {{item.counter}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understand from question what your counter should do, but i think it needs to change these lines

```
Vue.set(this.count, this.count[val], 0);
this.count[val]++;
```

to this 1 line:

```
Vue.set(this.count, val, this.count[val]+1);
```

And I think you need to change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/jqr0nzte/70/).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Vuejs documentation [Vuejs Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

- When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
- When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same as vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity system:

```
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

The example would be like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#page',
  data: {
    arr: [1, 2 ,3],
    count: [0, 0 ,0]
  },
  methods: {
    addEll: function() {
       this.arr.push(this.arr.length + 1);
       this.count.push(0);
    },
    incrementio: function(index) {
       this.$set(this.count, index, this.count[index] + 1)
    },
  },
  computed: {
     visibleList: function(){
       return this.arr;
     }
  }
})
```